# Type LoginPage is part of the declarations of two modules

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm pretty new on Angula2 and Ionic world, so, I'm currently developing a tabs app with various pages, components and providers. It works fine when i run *ionic serve* command. Now I'm trying to generate the APK and I get that error.
In my app.module.ts i have declarations like that :

```
@NgModule({declarations: [
    MyApp,
    MenuPage,
    OrdersPage,
    DatiPage,
    ....
TextImg]
```

and also, every page has it's own page.module.ts file containing something like :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DatiPage } from './dati';

@NgModule({declarations: [
    DatiPage,
  ],imports: [
  IonicPageModule.forChild(DatiPage),
 ],
})
export class DatiPageModule {}
```

If i remove one of the two declarations, ionic serve webapp stops working. Otherway, if I try to build apk, i get this :

[image]

Sorry long paths, but that's it. Do someone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I've added the answer before knowing it was a duplicate question. Thanks **[Duannx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4254681/duannx)** for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

> every page has its own page.module.ts file containing something like [...]

Seems like you're using lazy-loaded pages. Since each page is loaded only when needed, you need to remove these pages from the `app.module.ts` file

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      MyApp,
      // MenuPage, // <---- Remove the pages from the app module
      // OrdersPage,
      // DatiPage,
      ....
      TextImg
    ]
    //...
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Now each page should be `declared` only in its own module (this should remove the *type ... is part of the declarations of two modules* error)

And since these pages are being lazy-loaded, when you need to navigate to any of these pages, you need to use a string with its name and **not the component name**:

```
// When setting the page in the app.component.ts page
rootPage:any = 'HomePage';
```

Please also notice that since it's a string, you don't need to import the `HomePage` in any file.

You can find more information about lazy-loading in these two blog posts from Ionic's blog:

- **[Ionic and Lazy Loading Pt 1](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/)**
- **[Ionic and Lazy Loading Pt 2](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer sebaferreras, I did like you said but still it's not working. I gave a look at the first question of which mine is a duplicate and I don't get something. @snorkpete says to remove AddEvent from declarations and imports, and import "AddEventModule" instead, adding then "AddEventModule" on imports, but he also has a "AddEvent" declared on entryComponents.. Is that a refuse? Or the "AddEvent" has to be in entryComponents? I suppose no, because no "AddEvent" is on top imports